# CakePHP saving hasMany associated data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have two MySQL tables.

1) post table: each item has an unique id.

```
id | title | content | ... 
1  | Hi    | Oh~     | ...
```

2) tag table: each item's id is not unique.

```
id | description   | 
1  | Meow          |
1  | Cat           |
```

In my models I have declared that Post hasMany Tag and Tag belongsTo Post:

```
//in Post model
var $hasMany = array(
    'Tag' => array(
        'className'     => 'Tag',
        'foreignKey'    => 'id',
        'dependent'=> true
    )

//in Tag model
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className'    => 'Post',
        'foreignKey'    => 'id'
    )
);
```

Now I am trying to save changes I made to a post into the database in my Posts Controller:

```
            $data = $this->request->data;
            foreach($data['Tag'] as &$tagg){
                    if($tagg["description"]!=""){
                        $tagg['id'] = $data['Post']['id'];
                    }
                }
            if ($this->Post->saveAll($data,array('deep'=>TRUE))) {
                 var_dump($data);
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Saved.'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Not Saved.'));
            }
```

After submitting the data, it flashed `Saved` but it is not saving anything to Tag table. It only saved data to the Post table.

Here is the result of var_dump:

```
array (size=2)
  'Post' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'aa' (length=2)
      'content' => string 'hi' (length=2)
      'url' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  'Tag' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'description' => string 'sadsad' (length=6)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
      5 => &
        array (size=1)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
```

How can I save all the data to both tag and post table? And where do I go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How does your form in the view looks like? Are you trying to save new tags with post?

Comment: "Tag" Table not containing post_id field, please add that and try. Because that is cakephp standard.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pankaj said in the children table you need to have unique id (autoincrement, primary key) as well as a field which contain the relation between posts and tags and by cake's standard it should be labelled post_id. Then toy should remove the foreach(){} block or at least in the loop remove the empty rows before submit

Answer (score -1):

In your PostsController, try adding:

```
public $uses = array('Post', 'Tag');
```

This is not the complete answer, but you will struggle with this for a long time without at least adding this line. You need to post your view as well and show how you're using the form helpers.